# Добавить параметр в запрос к роуту

Tags: java, spring, crud

Этот код рабочий (ниже). При запросе http://localhost:8080/api/users/user?id=1 возвращает пользователя с id = 1.
Чтобы получить список пользователей http://localhost:8080/api/users

Вопрос в следующем, как реализовать контроллер, чтобы получать пользователей по id следующим запросом? http://localhost:8080/api/users?id=1

Если я не указываю роут @GetMapping("/user") то берется соотвественно основной - @RequestMapping("/api/users")
При сборке возникает ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity registration(@RequestBody UsersEntity user) {
        try {
            userService.registration(user);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Пользователь успешно создан");

        } catch (UserAlreadyExistException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }

            catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Произошла ошибка");
        }


    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity getUsers() {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getAll());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Произошла ошибка");
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity getOneUser(@RequestParam Long id) {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getOne(id));

        } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }

          catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Произошла ошибка");
        }
    }
}
```

service

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    public UsersEntity registration(UsersEntity user) throws UserAlreadyExistException {
        if(userRepo.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null) {
            throw new UserAlreadyExistException("Пользователь с таким email адресом существует"); // проверка на пользователя в базе данных
        }

        return userRepo.save(user);
    }

    public Iterable <UsersEntity> getAll() {
        return userRepo.findAll();

    }

    public UsersEntity getOne(Long id) throws UserNotFoundException {
        UsersEntity user = userRepo.findById(id).get();
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException("Пользователь не найден");
        }
        return user;
    }


}
```

Comment: У вас на скрине один путь до метода getOneUser, а в коде другой. В коде, который вы привели вроде бы нет такой ошибки.

Comment: Все верно. Просто хотел узнать есть ли вариант реализовать чуть по-другому, чтобы получать пользователя по id следующим запросом http://localhost:8080/api/users?id=1 без изменения роута? Не в таком виде http://localhost:8080/api/users/1 , http://localhost:8080/api/users/user?id=1

Comment: Либо `@RequestParam` либо `@PathVariable`. Можно извратиться и вытащить id из `@RequestBody`.

Comment: Понял благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное наиболее удобное решение в данном случае реализовать следующим образом:

пример запроса: http://localhost:8080/api/users/2

```
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity getOneUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getOne(id));

        } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }

          catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Произошла ошибка");
        }
    }
}
```